# iOS16 - How to navigate through hidden links with an optional value?

Tags: swiftui-navigationlink, ios16

I previously used an optional value to click a hidden link to navigate in my app. Something like this example in [Hacking With Swift](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-programmatic-navigation-in-swiftui):

```
@State private var selection: String? = nil

var body: some View {
   ....
      NavigationLink(destination: Text("View A"), tag: "A", selection: $selection) { EmptyView() }
      NavigationLink(destination: Text("View B"), tag: "B", selection: $selection) { EmptyView() }

      Button("Tap to show A") {
           selection = "A"
      }

      Button("Tap to show B") {
           selection = "B"
      }
```

With iOS 16 this is deprecated. I am currently setting an optional value and when it's not nil I want a link to open. I can't figure out how to do it with the new NavigationLink/Value/Destination combination. Has anyone else figured out how to do it?

I created a new projects and switched ContentView to the following:

```
private enum Destinations: Hashable {
    case empty
    case general
    case myQuestionView(String)
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selection: Destinations?
    
    @State private var mySelectedString: String?
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationSplitView {
            List(selection: $selection) {
                NavigationLink(value: Destinations.general) {
                    Text("Example")
                }
                if mySelectedString != nil {
                    NavigationLink(value: Destinations.myQuestionView(mySelectedString!)) {
                        Text("String: \(mySelectedString ?? "no name")")
                    }
                }
                Button(action: {
                    mySelectedString = "A Name"
                }, label: {
                    Text("Set the value")
                })
            }
        } detail: {
            NavigationStack {
                switch selection ?? .empty {
                case .empty: Text("Please select an option to continue.")
                case .general: Text("Result of this option")
                case .myQuestionView(let aString): Text("Hello \(aString)")
                }
                
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Here the `Set the value` button sets the selectedString which makes the link appear but I can't make it automatically navigate AND, ideally, it would never appear and would navigate when the value is set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay... the answer is super simple and leaving the question and this answer up in case it helps someone else.

You don't need to have an invisible `NavigationLink`. You just need to set the selection to the new destination: `selection = .myQuestionView("this name instead")`. Or, if I was using the navigation path `NavigationStack(path: $myPath)` I'd just append it.

So in this specific example `ContentView` would now be:

```
private enum Destinations: Hashable {
    case empty
    case general
    case myQuestionView(String)
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selection: Destinations?
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationSplitView {
            List(selection: $selection) {
                NavigationLink(value: Destinations.general) {
                    Text("Example")
                }
                Button(action: {
                    selection = .myQuestionView("this name instead")
                }, label: {
                    Text("Set the value")
                })
            }
        } detail: {
            NavigationStack {
                switch selection ?? .empty {
                case .empty: Text("Please select an option to continue.")
                case .general: Text("Result of this option")
                case .myQuestionView(let aString): Text("Hello \(aString)")
                }
                
            }
        }

    }
}
```